# iText7 superimpose overlay two PDF as one new issue

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to superimpose or overlay two A4 PDF pages as one page in a new A4 PDF
I've tried reversing the order of the source docs, checked they are really A4, but each time I run it the second object is always added approx 10mm to the right and up.
Is there some sort of starting point or margin I have to set before adding the second object?

```
PdfDocument pdfDocNew = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfDocument pdfDocSrc1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source1));
PdfDocument pdfDocSrc2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source2));

PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
PdfPage targetPage = pdfDocNew.AddNewPage(pageSize);
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(targetPage);

PdfPage currentPage = pdfDocSrc1.GetPage(1);
Rectangle orig = currentPage.GetPageSize();
var width = 0.99f;
var height = 0.99f;
AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(width,height);
canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
var height1 = orig.GetHeight();
var width2 = orig.GetWidth() / 2;
var height2 = orig.GetHeight() / 2;
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = currentPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDocNew);
canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,0,0);

currentPage = pdfDocSrc2.GetPage(1);
pageCopy = currentPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDocNew);
canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,0,0);
pdfDocNew.Close();
```

Comment: if I change the second
 canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,0,0);
to 
 canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,-25,-25);
it lines up as required... I just don't understand why it is needed.. why doesn't the first AddXObject also get displaced?

Comment: Each page has a crop box which defines the page coordinate system, in particular where its origin is - it is not necessarily in its lower left corner. Probably your PDFs have crop boxes which in their lower left have the coordinates (25,25), so you have to counteract that by adding at (-25,-25). If you shared example PDFs to reproduce this, we could verify that.

Comment: if I do  
    Rectangle cropBox = page1.GetCropBox();
on both input pdfs they all report 595x842 same as page size.

Comment: Have you looked at their exact coordinates, not merely their size? Using `GetLeft()` and `GetBottom()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou @mkl
GetLeft() and GetBottom() both returned 29.17
so I adjust by those now (via variables but effectively)
canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,-29.17,-29.17)